# Can the 'returning' clause return source columns that are not inserted?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Here's a minimal example of my real-world problem:

```
create table t(id serial primary key, rnd double precision);
```

*of course you can return the inserted columns with a `returning` clause:*

```
with w as (insert into t(rnd) values(random()) returning *)
insert into t(rnd) select random() from w returning *;
/*
| ID |            RND |
|----|----------------|
|  9 | 0.203221440315 |
*/
```

*you can also return a literal:*

```
with w as (insert into t(rnd) values(random()) returning *)
insert into t(rnd) select random() from w returning *, 1.0 dummy;
/*
| ID |            RND | DUMMY |
|----|----------------|-------|
| 11 | 0.594980469905 |     1 |
*/
```

*but you can't return the source columns:*

```
with w as (insert into t(rnd) values(random()) returning *)
insert into t(rnd) select random() from w returning *, w.rnd;
/*
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "w": with w as (insert into t(rnd) values(random()) returning *) insert into t(rnd) select random() from w returning *, w.rnd
*/
```

Is there any way I can get `w.rnd` out of the final `returning` clause?

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=029ab5cd72721c14013bd5824bcfbaa4)*

Comment: In MS SQL Server only the MERGE statement allows for additional columns to be returned. Maybe that will work for postgres too.

Comment: I solved [a similar problem for `UPDATE` in this related answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957), but this won't work for `INSERT`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation on the `RETURNING` clause says:

> An expression to be computed and returned by the INSERT command after
>   each row is inserted. The expression can use any column names of the
>   table named by table_name. Write * to return all columns of the
>   inserted row(s).

This clearly does not apply for columns from an other table.

Though I don't really get the point of the problem (i. e. why you do this - I imagine it is because it is a bit too abstract version of the original one), a possible solution can be:

```
WITH w AS (INSERT INTO t(rnd) VALUES (random()) RETURNING *),
     x AS (INSERT INTO t(rnd) SELECT random() FROM w RETURNING *)
SELECT w.rnd, x.rnd
  FROM w, x;
```

That is, you can put more than one writable CTE to the beginning of a query.  Please see this in action on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fe61dbc3cb0453c0b61e8ac000e2ed32).