# How to split one table into two in a single statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I've got an old table I want to split into two, but I'd rather not run two near-identical queries across the whole thing. The following does not work because [you can only return column from the table you're inserting into](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50711/3322):

```
WITH comment_insert AS (
    INSERT INTO comments (content)
        SELECT content
          FROM old_schema.comments
          JOIN area ON area.id = old_schema.comments.area_id
        RETURNING id, area.id AS area_id
)
INSERT INTO area_comment (parent_id, area_id)
SELECT comment_insert.id,
       comment_insert.area_id
  FROM transitional_schema.mon_area_comment
```

Is it possible to do something *like* this, putting some columns in the "parent" table and the parent *ID* plus some other columns into another table, using a single query?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in any way that's worth doing.  invollving any proececureal language is likely to be slower than doing the two inserts.

Comment: @Jasen I've not said anything about procedural languages. I'm asking how to do this ***in SQL.*** If it's not possible using a single query I will just use two, with the associated overhead and duplication.

Comment: if you don'r need to keep the source table you could drop columns and rename the table for the second copy.  proceural language was an example of a way that not worth doing.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think that's doable. I'm accessing it via a foreign data wrapper, so it's not even on the same cluster. Copying the table schema and data across before starting the migration is going to be more work than two inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Modelling scheme:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE old_table (id INT, val1 INT, val2 INT);
> INSERT INTO old_table VALUES (11,111,1111), (22,222,2222);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE new_table1 (id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, val1 INT);
> CREATE TABLE new_table2 (id_table1 INT, val2 INT);
> ```

> ```
> WITH cte AS 
> (
> INSERT INTO new_table1 (val1)
> SELECT val1
> FROM old_table
> RETURNING id, val1
> )
> INSERT INTO new_table2 (id_table1, val2)
> SELECT cte.id, old_table.val2
> -- use both old table
> FROM old_table
> -- and CTE table
> JOIN cte 
>     ON old_table.val1 = cte.val1; -- the relation is set 
>                                   -- by the value saved into new table
>                                   -- not by old primary index
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM new_table1;
> SELECT * FROM new_table2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val1
> -: | ---:
>  1 |  111
>  2 |  222
>
> id_table1 | val2
> --------: | ---:
>         1 | 1111
>         2 | 2222
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2119476947be42846786695a427162fe)*

Pay attention - in last INSERT both CTE and source table are used.

Comment: I have to check whether this will work, because if I understand correctly this solution relies on the primary key columns from the old table all being inserted into the *parent* table.

Comment: @l0b0 No... `new_table.id` may be new-valued identity field - this changes nothing. Anycase the last query takes referential value from NEW table (`cte.id`), not from the old one (`old_table.id`). The example edited.

Comment: @l0b0 Example edited, `new_table1.id` is changed to identity.